# move_base global/local planner configuration

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having a hard time setting move_base parameters for my global/local planner. I would expect move_base to complain about invalid parameters instead of using old parameters as it seems. Is there a cache of some sort for the planner configs?

For example in my costmap_common_params_waffle.yaml I have this:

```
map_type: costmap
observation_sources: scan
scan: {sensor_frame: base_scan, data_type: LaserScan, topic: scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

Now if I comment out all lines, move_base still subscribes to the topic 'scan'. If I rename the topic from 'scan' to 'scan-123' (non-existent topic), move_base still subscribes to the topic 'scan'. In fact, even if I don't even pass this file to move_base it still behaves the same:

```
<rosparam file="$(find turtlebot3_navigation)/param/costmap_common_params_waffle.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
```

This is a real mystery to me. Is there a way I can debug move_base and see where it gets it's configs from?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347469/move_base-global/local-planner-configuration/) by [dschnabel](https://answers.ros.org/users/51661/dschnabel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2020-03-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bob-ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/45543/bob-ros/) on 2020-03-25**:
Just FYI, if you don't restart the roscore or clear your rosparams manually they will remain even if you comment them out.

**Comment by [dschnabel](https://answers.ros.org/users/51661/dschnabel/) on 2020-03-26**:
That was my problem! I needed to delete the rosparams in order to clear the cache (e.g. 'rosparam delete /move_base/global_costmap/obstacle_layer/scan/sensor_frame').

Thanks @bob-ROS for pointing that out. Small details you don't get taught when you study ROS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See comment from bob-ROS:

> Just FYI, if you don't restart the roscore or clear your rosparams manually they will remain even if you comment them out.

I needed to delete the rosparams in order to clear the cache:

```
rosparam delete /move_base/global_costmap/obstacle_layer/scan/sensor_frame
```

---

Originally posted by [dschnabel](https://answers.ros.org/users/51661/dschnabel/) with karma: 103 on 2020-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0